# Map over List[Class[_ <: X]] to get List[Foo[A]]

Tags: scala

Given the following types:

```
scala> trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case class Girl extends Parent
defined class Girl

scala> case class Boy extends Parent
defined class Boy
```

And then a `List[Class[_ <: Parent]]`:

```
scala> List[Class[_ <: Parent]](Boy().getClass, Girl().getClass)
res18: List[Class[_ <: Parent]] = List(class Boy, class Girl)
```

Then, I define a class, `Blah`, that accepts a type parameter that's a child of `Parent`. It has an implicit `Manifest[A]` and a single method.

```
scala> class Blah[A <: Parent](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) { 
       |     def getRuntimeClass = m.runtimeClass 
       |} 
defined class Blah
```

Why can't I `map` over the `List[Class[_ <: Parent]]` to get a `List[Blah[A]]`?

```
scala> res18.map(x => new Blah[x.type])
<console>:15: error: type arguments [x.type] do not conform to class Blah's type parameter bounds [A <: Parent]
              res18.map(x => new Blah[x.type])
                                 ^
```

**EDIT**

I could do something like this:

```
scala> res18.map(_ => new Blah)
res20: List[Blah[Nothing]] = List(Blah@5de6af79, Blah@540a6118)
```

But then I get `Nothing` as the type, which makes sense. This outcome isn't acceptable.

```
scala> res20(0)
res21: Blah[Nothing] = Blah@5de6af79

scala> res21.getRuntimeClass
res22: Class[_] = class scala.runtime.Nothing$
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you store a list of classes but you need a list of manifests.

```
trait Parent
case class Girl() extends Parent
case class Boy() extends Parent

val l = List(manifest[Girl], manifest[Boy])

class Blah[A <: Parent](implicit m: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]) { 
   def getRuntimeClass = m.runtimeClass 
}
```

then you can just use the manifests as implicit parameters and the compiler will infer the right thing

```
import scala.reflect._
val res = l.map {
    implicit m =>
    new Blah()
}
res(0).getRuntimeClass
```

yields

```
Class[_] = class Girl
```